# Как запустить трассировку svc-служб IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Добрый день! Имеется сервер приложений IIS 6.1, где крутятся службы(написанные на C#), которые выполняют различные запросы в сервер БД и возращают результаты для клиентстких приложений. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы сервер IIS выполнял трассировку работы одной(или всех) службы в какой нибудь текстовый файл. Обращение в гугл особо не помогло.